# Rust problem with lifetime and borrowing -> argument requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`

Tags: rust

I want to run a test defined here:

```rust
fn run<'a>(args: &[&str], expected_value: &'a str) -> TestResult {
    Command::cargo_bin("echor")?
    .args(args)
    .assert()
    .success()
    .stdout(expected_value);
    Ok(())
}

#[test]
fn hello2() -> TestResult {
    let expected = "Hello there\n";
    run(&["Hello there"], expected)
}
```

I receive an error:

```bash
 |   fn run<'a>(args: &[&str], expected_value: &'a str) -> TestResult {
   |          --                 -------------- `expected_value` is a reference that is only valid in the function body
   |          |
   |          lifetime `'a` defined here
32 | /     Command::cargo_bin("echor")?
33 | |     .args(args)
34 | |     .assert()
35 | |     .success()
36 | |     .stdout(expected_value);
   | |                           ^
   | |                           |
   | |___________________________`expected_value` escapes the function body here
   |                             argument requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`
```

This is my beginning with rust, and I don't know how to handle this. Could you describe what I am doing wrong?
I tried many things, changing to String type and converting to str. But nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stdout need a static arguments ,the arguments is live long with the program, but you give it a reference with lifetime, you can give it a reference and convert it to a string literal then give it to stdout methods;like below:

```
fn run<'a>(args: &[&str], expected_value: &'a str) -> TestResult {
    let expected_value_static = expected_value.to_string();
    Command::cargo_bin("echor")?
        .args(args)
        .assert()
        .success()
        .stdout(expected_value_static);
    Ok(())
}
```